# How to handle this context with enum? SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'type'

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table with this structure:

```
Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('question');
    $table->enum('type', ['text', 'option', 'checkbox', 'select', 'long_text']);
    $table->integer('conf_id');
});
```

Then I have a form to create a question. This form has a title and a type for the question. The type is a select menu with this options "Long Text", "Text", "Select Menu",
"Checkbox", "Radio button".

My doubt is:

For example like this if the user introduces a title for the question and then a type, for example the type value "Long Text", this type value it will only work if the langue it is in english, but for example if the user change the language for another language the "Long Text" option will have a different value and the store will not work.

Do you know how to handle this properly?

Im getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'type' at row 1

 (SQL: insert into `questions` (`conf_id`, `question`, `type`) 

 values (1, test, Text))
```

To store the question:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'question' => 'required|max:255|string',
        'type' => 'required|'in:text, option, checkbox, select, long_text',
    ]);
    $conf = Conf::find($id);
    Question::create([
        'conf_id' => $conf->id,
        'question' => $request->question,
        'type' => $request->type,
    ]);
```

Type form field:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label for="type">Type</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="type" id="type">
                    <option name="text">text</option>
                    <option name="long_text">Long Text</option>
                    <option name="checkbox">Select menu</option>
                    <option  name="radio_button">Radio button</option>
                    <option  name="select_menu">Checkbox</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: the value of the type should be independent from the language !

Comment: Thanks, but for example if the user selects "long text" it will be stored with success but if the user selects another language, in the form "long text" will appear differently so it will not store because db expects one of this: "Long Text", "Text", "Select Menu", "Checkbox", "Radio button".

Comment: that's what i mean in the backend you will store all the time "long text" even if it's not english !

Comment: What maraboc said...

`<option name="long_text">Long Text</option>` you should do `<option value="long_text">Long Text</option>` instead. That way the server always receives "long_text" regardless of the text shown to the user.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianM i should have used an example as you did for more explanation :)